# Xcode Allocations Instrument - Listening to Memory Warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I am using the Allocations Instrument to enhance the performance of my app. I want to pay attention to memoryWarnings to make sure my app doesn't use up too much memory or crash.

I would like my entire app to listen to memoryWarings. I know I can use this to listen to certain warnings, but will the code below listen to everything? Also, where do I need to implement it? Do I need to put it in each View Controller or can I put it in the App Delegate?

```
- (id)init {
if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
    _cache = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(memoryWarning:) 
    name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
    }
return self;
}
```

I know I need to implement the method that listens to the memoryWarnings. Will this listen to all memoryWarnings? Also, do I need to place this in every viewController? Or can I place this somehow in the AppDelegate?

```
- (void)memoryWarning:(NSNotification*)note {
    [_cache removeAllObjects];
}
```

Any guidance would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I suggest changing your approach and use [NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this. It will automatically drop unneeded cache entries when app is low on memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view  controller already have a method to listen to memory warnings

```
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to call [_cache removeAllObjects]; in the didReceiveMemoryWarning method?

Comment: No. `[_cache release]` . It will send release message on all objects in the _cache dictionary

Comment: Ya.. I dont know the purpose of your _cache. `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method is invoked by the system when the memory become in sufficient. If your cache in needed further do not wait for `didReceiveMemoryWarning` release the _cache in the `dealloc` itself

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why I would need it - following a tutorial that recommended to clear cache upon memoryWarnings